# 2 positional argument(s) expected, but 1 found. and The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Object>'

Tags: flutter, dart, filepicker

I have been able to open my files using the [file picker package](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) but I am to save the result path to the **pdfFile** variable.

This is the variable

```
File? pdfFile;
```

I am getting the error from the code below

```
onPressed: () async {
          FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
            type: FileType.custom,
            allowMultiple: false,
          ); //allowedExtensions: ['pdf', 'doc']);
          if (result == null) return;
          final path = result.files.single.path;
          setState(() {
            pdfFile = File(path); //2 positional argument(s) expected, but 1 found. and The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Object>'.
          });
        }
```

Comment: Can you include your top imports

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure the `import` section is correct.

```dart
import 'dart:io';   // for File
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';   // for FilePickerResult
```

Comment: I have already imported those

Comment: There could be overlap with others, can you include all the imports on question

Comment: `import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cocoabod/constants.dart' as constants;
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';`

Comment: Please these are my imports

Comment: can you try with `flutter clean` and upgrading the packages

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors.

1. Two arguments are needed but you are sending only one
2. The argument requests a list but you are sending an optional string.